# Java/Using increment operator to count heads/tails

Tags: increment, operator-keyword

I have to write a program which will take 8 entries of heads or tails outcomes. The user enters h or t 8 times then the program should output # of heads and tails as well as the percentage of each. I know that I need the increment operator but how do I isolate t and h as different variables? I can't use if statements or loops..

Comment: You don't need two variables. You only have to count one of them. Count the number of h inputs (or t, if you prefer). If you're getting 8 inputs, and you count 5 h's, then 8 - 5 = 3 tails.

Comment: that makes sense thank you